# Make calculations into a variable within a list

Tags: r, list, conditional-statements, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

I would like to make some specific calculation within a large dataset.

**This is my MWE using an API call (takes 3-4 sec ONLY to Download)**

```
devtools::install_github('mingjerli/IMFData')

library(IMFData)

fdi_asst   <- c("BFDA_BP6_USD","BFDAD_BP6_USD","BFDAE_BP6_USD")
databaseID <- "BOP"
startdate  <- "1980-01-01"
enddate    <- "2016-12-31"
checkquery <- FALSE
FDI_ASSETS   <- as.data.frame(CompactDataMethod(databaseID, list(CL_FREA = "Q", CL_AREA_BOP = "", CL_INDICATOR_BOP= fdi_asst), startdate, enddate, checkquery))
```

my dataframe 'FDI_ASSETS' looks like this (I provide a picture *instead of head() for convenience*)

[image]

the last column is a list and contains three more variables:

```
head(FDI_ASSETS$Obs)
[[1]]
    @TIME_PERIOD        @OBS_VALUE @OBS_STATUS
1        1980-Q1  30.0318922812441        <NA>
2        1980-Q2  23.8926174547104        <NA>
3        1980-Q3   26.599634375058        <NA>
4        1980-Q4  32.7522451203517        <NA>
5        1981-Q1   44.124979234001        <NA>
6        1981-Q2  35.9907120805994        <NA>
```

**MY SCOPE**

I want to do the following:

1. if/when the `"@UNIT_MULT == 6"` then divide the `"@OBS_VALUE"` in `FDI_ASSETS$Obs` by 1000
2. if/when the `"@UNIT_MULT == 3"` then divide the `"@OBS_VALUE"` in `FDI_ASSETS$Obs` by 1000000

**UPDATE**

Structure of `FDI_ASSETS` looks like this:

```
str(FDI_ASSETS)
'data.frame':   375 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ @FREQ       : chr  "Q" "Q" "Q" "Q" ...
 $ @REF_AREA   : chr  "FI" "MX" "MX" "TO" ...
 $ @INDICATOR  : chr  "BFDAE_BP6_USD" "BFDAD_BP6_USD" "BFDAE_BP6_USD" "BFDAD_BP6_USD" ...
 $ @UNIT_MULT  : chr  "6" "6" "6" "3" ...
 $ @TIME_FORMAT: chr  "P3M" "P3M" "P3M" "P3M" ...
 $ Obs         :List of 375
  ..$ :'data.frame':    147 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ @TIME_PERIOD: chr  "1980-Q1" "1980-Q2" "1980-Q3" "1980-Q4" ...
  .. ..$ @OBS_VALUE  : chr  "30.0318922812441" "23.8926174547104" "26.599634375058" "32.7522451203517" ...
  .. ..$ @OBS_STATUS : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ :'data.frame':    60 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ @TIME_PERIOD: chr  "2001-Q1" "2001-Q3" "2002-Q1" "2002-Q2" ...
  .. ..$ @OBS_VALUE  : chr  "9.99999999748979E-05" "9.99999997475243E-05" "9.8999999998739E-05" "-9.90000000342661E-05" ...
  ..$ :'data.frame':    63 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ @TIME_PERIOD: chr  "2001-Q1" "2001-Q2" "2001-Q3" "2001-Q4" ...
  .. ..$ @OBS_VALUE  : chr  "130.0149" "189.627" "3453.8319" "630.483" ...
  ..$ :'data.frame':    17 obs. of  2 variables:
```

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded your data and it is quite complicated. I have removed my wrong answer so that you can get it answered by @akrun or someone similar :)  I don't have the time to parse through it right now.

Comment: I cannot access the `OBS_VALUE' as you say. Note that the `OBS_VALUE' is a vector within a list. In other words, should be the equivalent of: `FDA_ASSETS$Obs$Obs$@OBS_VALUE' ....

Comment: Do a dput(head(FDI_ASSETS,2)) and post so we can see full data structure. It might be as simple as changing FDI_ASSETS$@OBS_VALUE to FDI_ASSETS$@OBS_VALUE[[2]] in all cases in the statement.

Comment: I think the FDI_ASSETS$Obs[[2]] is again not correct, because my elemnt in my case is a whole dataframe with three variables including the one I am interested in. Can you please see the datastructure, I have posted an update for you.

Comment: I downloaded your data and it is quite complicated. I have removed my wrong answer so that you can get it answered by @akrun or someone similar :)  I don't have the time to parse through it right now.

Comment: No worries. But I think we were close. I think the only difficulty was to correctly access the right data.

Comment: You can get out the data you want by sapply(FDI_ASSETS$Obs, "[[", 2).  That will give you the ability to change to numeric and do what you will, but I don't know how to modify the existing data structure.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution

```
list_assets<-list(FDI_ASSETS=FDI_ASSETS, Portfolio_ASSETS=Portfolio_ASSETS, other_invest_ASSETS=other_invest_ASSETS, fin_der_ASSETS=fin_der_ASSETS, Reserves=Reserves)


for (df in list_assets){
for( i in 1:length(df$"@UNIT_MULT")){
  if (df$"@UNIT_MULT"[i]=="6"){
    df$Obs[[i]]$"@OBS_VALUE" <- as.numeric(df$Obs[[i]]$"@OBS_VALUE")
    df$Obs[[i]]$"@OBS_VALUE" <- df$Obs[[i]]$"@OBS_VALUE"/1000
  }  else if ((df$"@UNIT_MULT"[i]=="3")){
    df$Obs[[i]]$"@OBS_VALUE" <- as.numeric(df$Obs[[i]]$"@OBS_VALUE")
    df$Obs[[i]]$"@OBS_VALUE" <- df$Obs[[i]]$"@OBS_VALUE"/1000000
    }
}
}
```

Please let me know how I can modify the code in order to make it more efficient and avoid these loops.

Comment: Maybe now you can help me a bit. @akaDrHouse